# How can i convert sqlDatareader to List<>

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

I want to return list which will store the `sqldatareader` value. how can i do this..

Answer (score 11):

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var result = new List<Foo>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var foo = new Foo 
        {
            Prop1 = reader.GetInt32(0),
            Prop2 = reader.GetString(1),
        }
        result.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but prefer `result.Add( new Foo() { Prop1 = reader.GetInt32(0), Prop2 = reader.GetString(1) } );`

Answer (score 1):

Also check this previously asked qestion : [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

Check this for generic type :

```
public ConvertToList<T>(SqlDataReader sqldr, int index)
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            while (sqldr.Read())           {
               list.Add((T)sqldr.GetValue(index));               index++;   
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old discussion, but try this on for size.

Strongly type your fields, and cast your rows into a DbDataRecord object.
ex:

```
                    Dim _Query = (From row In _Results.Cast(Of DbDataRecord)().AsParallel()
                            Select New uTyping.Profile() With {
                                .Id = row(0),
                                .Firstname = row(6)
                            }).ToList()
```