# convert results of SQL statement to list

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to put the results of an SQL statement into a combo box on a form. I have trawled the net for an answer and I can't get further than this:

```
using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(
 Properties.Settings.Default.CW2_DBConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();

    List<Visit> rows = new List<Visit>();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PICKUP_ID FROM PICKUP";

    c.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {

    }

    cmbPickupID.Items.Add(rows);
}
```

I am not sure what to put in the while loop. I did have something like:

```
rows.Add(reader["PICKUP_ID"].ToString());
```

But obviously it didn't work. The Visit class has set and get for VisitID. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What kind of constructors does `Visit` have?

Comment: Both your SqlCeCommand and SqlCeDataReader need to be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: You don't need the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Secondly: if your `Visit` class has a property PICKUP_ID, and you are using a List of `Visit` items, then you need to add actual `Visits` to your list, not just strings, like this:

```
rows.Add(new Visit () {pickupid = reader["PICKUP_ID"].ToString()});
```

if you only need the id's, then you might as well just make a `List<string>`. The code you posted would work then.

Answer (score 3):

I thing you can use `Reflection` and some things else.

I suggest you to use `Dapper`.

You can use Dapper to convert a result of one query to one class.

For use dapper do this :

1 : right click on your project in `Visual studio` and select `Manage Nuget Packages`.

2 : in `search Online` text box type Dapper.

3 : after search this DLL on the web you can install that.(you most have a connection to internet).

4 : create your `Domain Class`

```
   private class DomainClass
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public int Sex { get; set; }
        public SexEnum sex { get; set; }
   }
```

5 : If you have some field that most convert to some field with deferent type(Enum type)
    do like `Sex` field.

6 : create connection string and `sqlConnection` object :

```
 var connectionStr = "Server=ArdalanShahgholiPC;Database=Dapper;User Id=sa;Password=sa;";
 SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
```

7 : and finilly use `Dapper.SqlMapper` to execute and convert query in to your domain class.

```
 IList<DomainClass> TestList = Dapper.SqlMapper.Query<DomainClass>(
                                sqlConn, "Select * From ATest").ToList();
```

at the end you can use `TestList`.

Comment: the easiest way to code

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` it's not needed is it?

Try this:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            cmbPickupID.Items.Add(reader["PICKUP_ID"].ToString());
        }
```