# Retrieve values from System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to retrieve the values of a datagrid which is bound to a sqlexecute query.

```
defects.DefectsDataGrid.DataContext = searchQuery.ExecuteReader();
```

Then, I am using SelectedCellsChanged event to do something with the DataGridRow selected.

When I put a breakpoint in, I can see the values beneath System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal > Non-public Members > _Values.  But I am not sure how to reference the _Values.

Code

```
private void DefectsDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve selected row
    var rows = DefectsDataGrid.SelectedItems;
    
    //This tells me I have one row, which is of type System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
    //How do I retrieve the values from this type?
           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    defects.DefectsDataGrid.DataContext = searchQuery.ExecuteReader();
```

I changed the above to the following, which gave me a data type of DataRowView instead of DataRecordInternal

```
    defects.DefectsDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.DefaultView;
```

This allowed me to easily reference the row in the event.

```
    private void DefectsDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve selected value from the row selected
        DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)DefectsDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        string phrase = dataRow[2];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to use a `DataReader` to cast your records to `IDataRecord`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034408/414314)

Comment: Franssu, I always put my results into a datareader or datatable and I have no problem using them, but I wanted to see if it was possible to bind direct to ExecuteReader, which seems fine, but retrieving the values from the event handler is causing me the problem.  Any ideas?