# C# - Load Dictionary from DataTable

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I need help in reading data from `DataTable` and adding key, value to a `Dictionary` object.

```
//Here is the object:
public class DBName
{
    public int ID { get; set; }                // key
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }   // value
}
```

My `DataTable` is getting data, but can't figure out how to add to `Dictionary`
reading `DataTable` and adding to `Dictionary` -

```cs
public static Dictionary<int,DBName> ReadToDictionary()
{
    string con = @"MyConnectionString;";
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);

    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT DisplayName AS DatabaseName, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(id)) AS ID
                    FROM dbo.MyTable
                    GROUP BY DisplayName";

    Dictionary<int, DBName> dictionaryDBName = new Dictionary<int, DBName>();
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlconn);
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        //how to add key and Value?
                        dictionaryDBName.Add(dr[1], DBName);
                    }
                    // anything here?
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return dictionaryDBName;
}
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are probably much better off just using a `DataReader`.** No need to fill a `DataTable` and then try looping through it, just loop the reader.

Further points:

- Don't swallow exceptions, deal with them properly
- You need to have a `using` on the connection, and then you don't need to call `Close`
- Are you aware of the differences between `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`?

```cs
public static Dictionary<int,DBName> ReadToDictionary()
{
      string con = @"MyConnectionString;";
      using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(con))
      {
            string sqlQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT
                                DisplayName AS DatabaseName
                                ,CAST(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(id)) AS int) AS ID
                            FROM
                                dbo.MyTable
                            GROUP BY 
                                DisplayName";

            sqlconn.Open();
            Dictionary<int, DBName> dictionaryDBName = new Dictionary<int, DBName>();
            using(SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlconn))
            using (var reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    DBName n = new DBName { ID = reader.GetInt32(1), DatabaseName = reader[0] as string};
                    dictionaryDBName.Add(n.ID, n);
                }
            }
    
            return dictionaryDBName;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry about query, I edited it. But where you have var reader, I get error System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.' I put next block in curly braces but still giving error.

Comment: regarding differences between RANK, DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER, they are all unique database names. but I guess you mean ROW_NUMBER will make more sense. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry forgot to `Open` the connection, have added. Probably yes you want `ROW_NUMBER`. `RANK` skips numbers when it gets a tie `1 2 2 4`, `DENSE_RANK` doesn't skip `1 2 2 3` and `ROW_NUMBER` is always sequential `1 2 3 4`. I would also advise to add an extra ordering column to ensure deterministic results.

Comment: Where you initialize DBName, I get error System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: First iteration itself it throws error 'System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'' on                                                                                                               
     DBName n = new DBName { ID = reader.GetInt32(1), DatabaseNm = reader[0] as string };  there are no nulls

Comment: error is on reader.GetInt32(1). whereas reader.GetString(0) is fetching data. Is that because it is not a physical column but ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: Ah, ["Return types: `bigint`"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) I've added `CAST` in the SQL but you could do it on the C# side also `(int) reader.GetInt64(1)`

Comment: apologies, I did not notice your change to sql statement. Yes, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the LINQ solution. The key is to use the powerful [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0) extension method.:

```
var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
var dataTable = new DataTable()
dataTable.Load(reader);
var dictionary = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary
( 
    x => (int)x[0],      //Convert column 0 into the dictionary's key
    x => (string)x[1]    //Convert column 1 into the dictionary's value
);
```

However, since SqlDataReader implements `IEnumerable`, you can skip the data table entirely like this:

```
var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
var dictionary = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().ToDictionary 
( 
    x => x.GetInt32(0),    //Convert column 0 into the dictionary's key
    x => x.GetString(1)    //Convert column 1 into the dictionary's value
);
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034408/2791540).

Comment: Do you know, I've been coding for years, consider myself very experienced with `SqlClient` and never knew that it implements `IEnumerable`. Unfortunately it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` also it seems to have other inefficiencies.