# Convert to List from DataReader in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sqldatareader

I have a query with a join like this:

```
string cmdString = "select tblPackages.*, tblPackageTypes.Name from tblPackages join tblPackageTypes on tblPackages.TypeId = tblPackageTypes.Id";
```

Now I use this SQL command and get back a datareader like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString,con);
SqlDataReader dr;
```

I want to populate values of data reader to a list. I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042404/how-to-put-values-from-datareader-into-listt) but I didn't get what I needed.

I have following columns output from the sql

```
Id, TypeId, AllowedSMS, TimeSpan, Price, TypeName.
```

I just want to pass them in the list. Please help me.. and i am new to asp.net

Comment: "but I didn't get what I needed" => What have you tried and what did you actually get?

Comment: @Koen the list is int but i needed list of all columns

Comment: Then you will have to create a class to hold the values of the columns you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, in your case, you need a **class** that can hold your columns:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int TypeId { get; set; }
   public bool AllowedSMS { get; set; }
   public string TimeSpan { get; set; }  
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public string TypeName { get; set; } 
}
```

Of course, since you didn't define what datatype those columns are, this is just a **guess** - you might need to adapt to your concrete needs.

And now, you need to iterate over the `SqlDataReader` and fetch the values from the data reader and populate your newly created class:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   List<MyClass> results = new List<MyClass>();

   while(dr.Read())
   {
       MyClass newItem = new MyClass();

       newItem.Id = dr.GetInt32(0);  
       newItem.TypeId = dr.GetInt32(1);  
       newItem.AllowedSMS = dr.GetBoolean(2);  
       newItem.TimeSpan = dr.GetString(3);
       newItem.Price = dr.GetDecimal(4);
       newItem.TypeName = dr.GetString(5);

       results.Add(newItem);
   }
}

// return the results here, or bind them to a gridview or something....
```

Comment: You could use Object Initializer to beautify this - newItem ;)

Comment: Is there a way (perhaps with Linq?) to select or cast `SqlDataReader dr` as `List<MyClass>` instead of interating each record with `dr.Read()`? Similar to a Lambda `.Select(a => new MyClass(){ Id = a.Id, TypeId = a.TypeId })` etc?