# Why String.Length is returned instead of actual value in DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, ilist

I have this code which builds an `IList<string>`:

```
IList<string> databases;

using (MySqlConnection _conn = Session.Connection)
using (MySqlCommand _cmd = _conn.CreateCommand("SHOW databases"))
{
    _cmd.Connection.Open ( );
    var _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

    databases = new List<string> ( _dr.SelectFromReader ( reader =>
        reader[ 0 ] is DBNull ? null : reader[ 0 ].ToString ( ) ) );

    _cmd.Connection.Close ( );
}

dgrid_Main.DataSource = databases;
```

Follow the workings of extension method [`SelectFromReader` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt/1464929#1464929).

The question is, **how come dgrid_Main is displaying the length of each database ...**
[image: display length of database names]
**... rather than the name?** I ran this test:

```
foreach (string db in databases)
{
    //  winform treeview control
    trv_ServerObjects.Nodes.Add ( db );
}
```

... I get the following result:
[image: display database name]

Comment: That is because it is attempting to show all the public properties of the projected value. The only public property of strong is Length

Comment: @Henk - indeed; the dangers of iSpelling

Comment: Nice not to have an Edit-window though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the DataSource property on dgrid_Main will bind each public property of the object in collection and not the object it self. And Length is one public-property of the string object.

When you actually iterate through the IList you get the list of database-names.

Try this..

```
dgrid_Main.DataSource = databases.ToList().Select(db => new { db });
```

Comment: +1: thanks for the explanation (to @Marc Gravell, too) Completely makes sense. Thanks for the tip ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that is happening, but have tried to use a binding source?

```
BindingSource binding1 = new List<string> ( _dr.SelectFromReader ( reader =>
    reader[ 0 ] is DBNull ? null : reader[ 0 ].ToString ( ) ) );
```

and then

```
dgrid_Main.DataSource = binding1
```