# Store Columns in List sql c#

Tags: c#, sql, list

```
while (Running)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        List<PackageDetailFile> pkgFiles = rdr.Read().ToString().ToList();
    }
}
```

Hello, the read() returns an inner joined table which has  7 8 columns, is it possible to store them inside List ?
if we can hows the correct casting of rdr.read(),   ( to string  to list ... ? )

Comment: It's not clear to me what the shape of these objects is or what types are being returned.  For one thing, `.ToString().ToList()` is going to give you a list of characters, which probably isn't what you want.  What is the type being returned by `.Read()`?  What is `rdr`?  What is `PackageDetailFile`?

Comment: rdr is my read execute thing, read() returns a whole table, packagedetailfile is also a table in my database, im really confused myself rightnow, written a bunch of codes that i got mixed up with.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The code above makes no sense and doesn't really show us what you are trying to do. You have some columns in the database. What are they? What do you want to do with them? What database? How many records do you want to pull up? Are you using something like LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: you can get an exception if the dataReader-instance has no rows!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the structure of your `PackageDetailFile` class and the underlying data you could do something like this

```
var packageDetailFiles = new List<PackageDetailFile>();

while (Running)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var detailFile = new PackageDetailFile();

        // the following will depend on your data structure and class properties
        detailFile.Property1 = rdr.GetString(0);
        detailFile.Property2 = rdr.GetString(1);
        detailFile.Property3 = rdr.GetString(2);

        packageDetailFiles.Add(detailFile);
    }
}
```

Note: You can use assemblies like AutoMapper to map from a data reader to a POCO reducing the need for the tedious `MyObject.MyProperty = dataReader[collectionIndex]` making your code far more readable and test friendly.

Answer (score 0):

try use GetValues method of rdr object. I suppose rdr is a SqlDataReader or another DataReader.

This method return an object array with all columns of the current row. 
After it you can store the object array in a list of objects. If you want to store in another type of list you must cast every element to the correct type before storing it.