# Return a List after reading from the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve all Names, from the Names tables in the database. I am unable to retrieve the data and return it as a lIst. how can i do it ?

```
public List<SelectListItem> getNames()
        {
             try
            {
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", con))
                {
                    con();
                    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                    return ?? // How to return the items that was returned 

                }
            }
 .......
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all rows returned as follows:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
while (dr.Read()) 
{
  var valueInColumn1 = dr[1];
  var valueInNamedColumn = dr["ColumnName"];
  ...
  items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = valueInColumn1.ToString(), Value = valueInNamedColumn.ToString()); 
}
return items;
```

Answer (score 1):

First instantiate the list to hold your items (you could also leave it null but that depends on what your callers expect) and then iterate over the [datareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods.aspx) by calling Read() until it returns false, which means no more records are available.

When the datareader has records you can fetch a column by calling one of the methods GetString, GetInt, GetLong etc supplying it the column you want to fetch as a parameter.

Construct the type you want to store in your list and add the retrieved values to its properties, add the new type to the List.

```
public List<SelectListItem> getNames()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    try
    {
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", con))
       {
           con();
           SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
           while (dr.Read())
           {
               list.Add(new SelectListItem { 
                          Value = dr.GetString(0), // first column, depends on your table 
                          Text = dr.GetString(1)  // second column, depends on your table
                }); 
           }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(r.Message);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: It says that SqlDataReader doesn't contain a definition for ReadString

Comment: I didn't had a compiler stand-by and looked up the wrong msdn-doc. sorry..fixed it...

Comment: If i use `GetInt ` then i have to replace `Value` with something else ?

Comment: Value is of type string so you could do dr.GetInt(0).ToString()

Answer (score 0):

See my code example:

```
  public static List<ActionItem> GetAllActions()
        {
            var actionItems = new List<ActionItem>();
            SqlDataReader actionsReader = CatalogDB.GetAllActions();

            try
            {
                while (actionsReader.Read())
                {
                    actionItems.Add(new ActionItem
                                        {
                                            Id = (int)actionsReader["Id"],
                                            Name = actionsReader["Name"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)actionsReader["Name"] : null,
                                            Description = (string)actionsReader["Description"],
                                            CreationDate = (DateTime)actionsReader["CreationDate"]                                                
                                        }
                        );
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                actionsReader.Close();
            }

            return actionItems;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. It can be any type. It's just an example. Or you aren't able to write your code following the example?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways, but this is probably the most straight forward.

```
public List<SelectListItem> getNames()
{
    var list = new List<SelectedListItem>();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Names", con))
        {
            con();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var item = new SelectedListItem();
                item.Value = dr[0];
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return list;
}
```