# Not able to search for a entry with duplicate values

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledb

Hi i have a database where my duplicated data (serial no) are entered. Like

```
Serial Nos  Chalan-no

Abcd1234    VS/12-13/T-S/187

Abcd1234    VS/12-13/T-S/187

Xyz11234    VS/12-13/T-S/130

Xyz11234    VS/12-13/T-S/174
```

In this if I search for  `abcd1234`  it will give me chalans-no `VS/12-13/T-S/187` for both entries. It's OK, but if I search for `xyz11234` it gives me chalans-no `VS/12-13/T-S/130` only, not `xyz11234` & `VS/12-13/T-S/174` as it checks for serial no and gives its first occurrence. But what if I want `xyz11234` & `VS/12-13/T-S/174`?

I am Using following code to search for Serial No and retrieve chalan_no for that:---

```
   Private Sub cmbSn_no_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbSn_no.SelectedIndexChanged
    'code to fill all details in text boxes when a Sr.No is selected in combobox

    Dim strSelVen As String = ("SELECT * FROM Duplicate_srno where sr_no= @srno")
    Dim comm_SelVen As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelVen, cnnOLEDB)
    comm_SelVen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srno", cmbSn_no.Text)
    cnnOLEDB.Open()

    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = comm_SelVen.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read = True Then

        cmbSn_no.Text = dr("Sr_no")
        cmbChal_no.Text = dr("chalan_no")

    End If
    cnnOLEDB.Close()
    strsrno = cmbSn_no.Text
    strchlno = cmbChal_no.Text
End Sub
```

Please  suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `If dr.Read = True Then ... End If` only does the `.Read` once, so you only retrieve one row. Try something like `Do While dr.read ... Loop`.

Comment: Thank You @Gord.. Its working Partly...if I have abcd1234---VS/12-13/T-S/186 and abcd1234---VS/12-13/T-S/187....it moves from VS/12-13/T-S/186 to VS/12-13/T-S/187 but not reverse.... If i select the second one and then go back to first one its not working...Code :--- ` Do While dr.Read = True

            cmbSn_no.Text = dr("Sr_no")
            cmbChal_no.Text = dr("chalan_no")

        Loop
       `                                                             Please resolve my problem.. Thank You...

Comment: @Harabati It looks like you're trying to add items to a combo box list. If so, then you'll need to use the appropriate `.method` to accomplish that. In VBA that would be `cmb_Sn_no.AddItem`; I'm sure it is something quite similar in VB.NET. (Right now you're probably just overwriting the `cmbSn_no.Text` property on each iteration of the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have following class:

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property SerialNumber As String
    Public Property ChalanNumber As String
End Class
```

The Table displaying the values in your question is using a `List(Of Data)`:

`Dim myList As New List(Of Data)()`

Then the operation should be:

`Dim selectedData = myList.Where(Function(e) e.SerialNumber = "xyz11234")`

Comment: Thank you @Felix. I am using the above code,..... I have just edited my post and added the code i am using..please check and suggest me .. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, don't know how to work with `OleDbDataReader`. But I guess your problem is, that you just display the first result of your query. You have to get a collection back from your SQL command. Maybe this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used an OleDBDataReader but if it's looks like it's only getting a single reader. Try the looping method.

Is there a way to read the entire table at once? In the SQL world it would be SqlDataAdapter.fill.