# Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion, nullable

```
Type t = typeof(int?); //will get this dynamically
object val = 5; //will get this dynamically
object nVal = Convert.ChangeType(val, t);//getting exception here
```

I am getting InvalidCastException in above code. For above I could simply write `int? nVal = val`, but above code is executing dynamically.

I am getting a value(of non nullable type like int, float, etc) wrapped up in an object (here val), and I have to save it to another object by casting it to another type(which can or cannot be nullable version of it). When

> Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

An `int`, should be convertible/type-castable to `nullable int`, what is the issue here ?

Comment: I guess maybe coz `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement `IConvertible`

Comment: This is rather fundamental.  Nullable is special, when you put it in an object then it either becomes null or becomes a boxed value of the value type.  So asking for an int? stored in an object just doesn't make sense.  Just ask for int.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You have to use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` to get underlying type of `Nullable`.

This is the method I use to overcome limitation of `ChangeType` for `Nullable`

```
public static T ChangeType<T>(object value) 
{
   var t = typeof(T);

   if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))) 
   {
       if (value == null) 
       { 
           return default(T); 
       }

       t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
   }

   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

non generic method:

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversion) 
{
   var t = conversion;

   if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))) 
   {
       if (value == null) 
       { 
           return null; 
       }

       t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
   }

   return Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

Comment: to user your method, I would need to do something like: `object nVal = ChangeType<int?>(val)`, here I need to tell the method about the generic argument(T), but I have `t` (or typeof(dataType)) at my disposal. How would I call your ChangeType method in my scenario ?

Comment: Added non generic version. See if it helps.

Comment: Getting compile error at `default(conversion)`, seems like similar issue.

Comment: Careful @gzaxx as `return null` is not the same as `default(T)`. If you're dealing with structs they are completely different things.

Comment: Non generic version will box struct and primitive types (as it takes and returns object) so returning null is valid. Anyone calling the functions will have to handle this by themselves.

Comment: I would suggest two more changes - do the null-check first (perfomance) and use "is" instead of == to avoid operator overloading surprises. so  start before getting the type t to see `if (value is null) return default(T);` - your thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this answer has an error. I do not understand so many votes here. The question is how to cast int no nullable<int>. Non-generic version is wrong because Nullable.GetUnderlying(int?) returns int. Thus you are doing here Convert.ChangeType(int, int). One thing helping here ia a direct cast to (T). But Convert.ChangeType() is wrong and not useful here.

Answer (score 14):

> For above I could simply write int? nVal = val

Actually, you can't do that either. There is no implicit conversion from `object` to `Nullable<int>`. But there *is* an implicit conversion from `int` to `Nullable<int>` so you can write this:

```
int? unVal = (int)val;
```

You can use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) method.

> Returns the **underlying type argument** of the specified nullable type.
>
> A generic type definition is a type declaration, such as Nullable,
>   that contains a type parameter list, and the type parameter list
>   declares one or more type parameters. A closed generic type is a type
>   declaration where a particular type is specified for a type parameter.

```
Type t = typeof(int?); //will get this dynamically
Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
object val = 5; //will get this dynamically
object nVal = Convert.ChangeType(val, u);// nVal will be 5
```

Here's a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/9t9ljU).

Comment: Wht if the object val = null;

Answer (score 3):

I think I should explain why the function does not work:

1- The line that throw the exception is as follows:

```
throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_FromTo", new object[]
  {
    value.GetType().FullName, 
    targetType.FullName
    }));
```

in fact the function search in the array Convert.ConvertTypes after that it see if the targer is an Enum and when nothing is found it throw the exception above.

2- the Convert.ConvertTypes is initialized as:

```
Convert.ConvertTypes = new RuntimeType[]
   {
      (RuntimeType)typeof(Empty), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(object), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(DBNull), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(bool), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(char), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(sbyte), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(byte), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(short), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(ushort), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(int), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(uint), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(long), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(ulong), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(float), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(double), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(decimal), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(DateTime), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(object), 
      (RuntimeType)typeof(string)
   };
```

So since the `int?` is not in the ConvertTypes array and not an Enum the exception is thrown.

So to resume, for the function Convert.ChnageType to work you have:

1. The object to be converted is IConvertible
2. The target type is within the ConvertTypes and not `Empty` nor `DBNull` (There is an explict test on those two with throw exception)

This behaviour is because `int` (and all other default types) uses `Convert.DefaultToType` as IConvertibale.ToType `implementation. and here is the code of the`DefaultToType`extracted` using `ILSpy`

```
internal static object DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    if (targetType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("targetType");
    }
    RuntimeType left = targetType as RuntimeType;
    if (left != null)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == targetType)
        {
            return value;
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[3])
        {
            return value.ToBoolean(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[4])
        {
            return value.ToChar(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[5])
        {
            return value.ToSByte(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[6])
        {
            return value.ToByte(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[7])
        {
            return value.ToInt16(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[8])
        {
            return value.ToUInt16(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[9])
        {
            return value.ToInt32(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[10])
        {
            return value.ToUInt32(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[11])
        {
            return value.ToInt64(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[12])
        {
            return value.ToUInt64(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[13])
        {
            return value.ToSingle(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[14])
        {
            return value.ToDouble(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[15])
        {
            return value.ToDecimal(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[16])
        {
            return value.ToDateTime(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[18])
        {
            return value.ToString(provider);
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[1])
        {
            return value;
        }
        if (left == Convert.EnumType)
        {
            return (Enum)value;
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[2])
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_DBNull"));
        }
        if (left == Convert.ConvertTypes[0])
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_Empty"));
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_FromTo", new object[]
    {
        value.GetType().FullName, 
        targetType.FullName
    }));
}
```

in other hand the cast is implemented by Nullable class itself and the definition is:

```
public static implicit operator T?(T value)
{
    return new T?(value);
}
public static explicit operator T(T? value)
{
    return value.Value;
}
```