# C# ASP.NET - No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function below, what I am trying to do, is connect to the database, run a query and put the results in a List and then return the list. This is what I came up so far,

```
 public class AirportClass
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> items;

        public AirportClass()
        {
            connectionString = @"Server=server;database=database;uid=username;pwd=password;";
        }

        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> getListItems()
        {
            items = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                string data = dataReader[0].ToString();
                items.Add(data);
            }
            connection.Close();
            return items;
        }
    }
```

I have ran the debugger and I can see that I am getting a connection and data is getting returned, I am just have trouble putting the items into a list. I get error when I add the `items.Add(data)` saying No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments....can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Just [check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx) `Dictionary.Add` syntax.

Comment: Why are you using `Dictionary`? Use `List` instead. `Dictionary` is used to store `key => value` data.

Comment: You're trying to put them into a dictionary, not a list

Comment: Anyway, I can't understand why IDE lets you to debug. It mustn't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a List and not a Dictionary:

```
 public class AirportClass
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private List<string> items;

        public AirportClass()
        {
            connectionString = @"Server=server;database=database;uid=username;pwd=password;";
        }

        public List<string> getListItems()
        {
            items = new List<string>();
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table");
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                string data = dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                items.Add(data);
            }
            connection.Close();
            return items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but it only returns the first row [0] how would I get all rows?

Comment: Use dataReader.GetString(0) instead of dataReader[0].ToString()

Comment: This gives me an error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Answer (score 2):

that's because `items` isn't a `List<T>`, it's a `Dictionary`
If you want to add to a Dictionary, you need to provide a `key` (first parameter) and a `value` (second parameter)

since your `value` type of the dictionary is `List<String>`, the second parameter must be a `List<string>`

Something along the lines of

```
items.Add(dataReader[0].ToString(), dataReader.ToList().convertAll(itm => itm.toString()));
```

Comment: note that you can't really cast a `DataReader` to `List<String>` like that. if you want to know how to do that, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Comment: I tried this `string data = dataReader[0].ToString();
                items.Add(data, data.ToList().convertAll(itm => itm.toString()));` and get an error around convertAll, `System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for 'convertAll'

Comment: Read the comment i posted above yours... in a perfect world, we'd be able to solve that issue so simply, but unfortunately, it's not a perfect world.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a key and a value to a Dictionary.