# Using AutoMapper with Data Reader

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I went through [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

I wanted to implement something like what is accepted as an answer in the above link.

Scenrio:

I am using OdbcDataReader to retrieve from the database.

And I have a Model Class . FYI , the properties of this class are exact replica of the column names from the database. I need to map these columns to the properties and return List
Can this be accomplished using Automapper.

Comment: Why can't you use the solution provided in that answer? It looks like it doesn't depend on a specific data reader implementation.

Comment: Just noting that in AutoMapper 1.1 - the last version for .Net 3.5 - **DataReader mappings are case sensitive**. To use this version in a case-insensitive manner AutoMapper needs patching as in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/90

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this

```
public List<T> ReadData<T>(string queryString)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                if (reader.HasRows)
                    return Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(reader);
        }

    return null;
}
```

Define your class

```
public class MarkType
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime inserted { get; set; }
}
```

Use

```
List<MarkType> lst = _helper.ReadData<MarkType>("SELECT [id],[name],[inserted] FROM [marktype]");
```

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable inputs

Comment: For anyone that refers to this after Dec 29, 2014, the Automapper project has removed support for `IDataReader` in Automapper versions 4.0 and higher. Refer to this [commit](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/33831e3b53ed1cd698558daa2db483906ec5c13a). Version 3.1.1 (available on NuGet) still has this functionality.

Comment: There is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Data) that adds this back in (currently it is in beta). [GitHub AutoMapper.Data](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data)