# AutoMapper is not returning data from DataTable

Tags: c#, object, datatable, dataset, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper plugin to map **DataTable** to **C# Object**. 
Here is my Code:

```
public List<MyDto> GetReport()
{
    List<MyDto> list = null;
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<MyDto>>();
    });
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    list = mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<MyDto>>(Odao.Inst.GetReport().Tables[0].CreateDataReader()).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

My **MyDto** class looks like this

```
public class MyDto
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Here, data is properly returning from my DataAccess Layer but when It maps to Object, list is coming as empty. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can't you use NHibernate to get data from the database? Something like `list = sessionService.GetDefaultSession().Query<MyDto>()`. As far as I know you can't get data from a database with AutoMapper, or am I wrong?

Comment: Data is returning using this line. `Odao.Inst.GetReport().Tables[0]` but, this data to Object mapping is not working

Comment: What if you try `cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<MyDto>>().ReverseMap()` just to see what happens?

Comment: No luck with `cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<MyDto>>().ReverseMap()`

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data/

Comment: What if you change mapping to `cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDto>();` and then `list<MyDto> = mapper.Map<IDataReader, MyDto>(Odao.Inst.GetReport().Tables[0].CreateDataReader()).ToList();`? That's what I'd try next. So maybe there is a problem with automapper and that list.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681102/using-automapper-with-data-reader - notice the comments on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using AutoMapper ver 3.3.1.
Basically, version 4 and above will not support this **IDataReader** functionality.

Now, the following code is working for me.

```
Mapper.Reset();
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDto>();
list = Mapper.Map<IDataReader,List<MyDto>>(Odao.Inst.GetReport().Tables[0].CreateDataReader()).ToList();
```

Comment: Because it was moved to AutoMapper.Data.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How to achieve the same using `AutoMapper.Data`? I didn't get any examples.

Comment: Browse the tests in the repo and look online.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you, got few.