# DataReader index outside bounds of Array

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I've the following method pulling information from a table;

```
public Customer GetCustomerDetails(int customerID)
    {
        Customer currentCustomer = null;
        try
        {
            using (cxn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCustomerInformation", cxn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID;
                    cxn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    currentCustomer = new Customer();
                    currentCustomer.CustomerID = customerID;

                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        currentCustomer.FirstName = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.firstName)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.Surname = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.surname)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.Email = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.email)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.Phone = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.phone)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.AddressLine1 = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.addressLine1)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.AddressLine2 = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.addressLine2)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.City = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.city)).ToString();
                        currentCustomer.County = dataReader.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(CustomerTableColumns.county)).ToString();
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                    cxn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return currentCustomer;
    }
```

However I keep getting the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array." on the last line in the while loop.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGetCustomerInformation]
@CustomerID INTEGER
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT
a.Firstname,
a.Surname,
a.Email,
a.Phone,
a.AddressLine1,
a.AddressLine2,
a.City,
County
FROM 
tblCustomers a
WHERE
a.CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

Comment: Replace `INTEGER` with `int` i `procedure

Comment: use dataReader["country"] etc instead of your enum

Comment: No Joy, If i change OUTPUT i get error `Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spGetCustomerInformation, Line 10
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type OUTPUT.
Parameter or variable '@CustomerID' has an invalid data type.`

Comment: I'll try without enum

Comment: Not related to question but if you are converting the datareader to object list why not use sql to linq. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Comment: Good question, project specification requires use of ADO and not LINQ, would much prefer to use LINQ!

Comment: Removing Enum works a charm!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is in the CustomerTableColumns, could you show us the code?

At first guess, I would say that the first value of your enum CustomerTableColumns is 1 to 8 and the datareader would expect to be 0 to 7

Comment: ` public enum CustomerTableColumns
    {
        customerID = 0,
        firstName,
        surname,
        email,
        phone,
        addressLine1,
        addressLine2,
        city,
        county
    }`

Comment: exactly the problem. firstName = 1 and county =8, your datareader will have at index 0 the firstName.