# SqlDataReader convert to List without loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can convert `SqlDataReader` to a list using a loop `While(dr.Read())`.

But, I need to convert `SqlDataReader` to a list.

Pseudo code:

```
con.Open();

string sqlBU = "select top 10 fname, iduser from users";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlBU, con);

using (SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    List<ListOfClass> customers = dr2.ToList();
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = lOfClass;

con.Close();
```

Class:

```
 public class ListOfClass
 {
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string iduser { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeSeries = new List<ListOfClass>();  
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (reader.HasRows)
  {
      timeSeries = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
           .Select(r => new ListOfClass
             {
                 fname = (string)r["fname"],
                            iduser = (string)r["iduser"]
             }).ToList();
  }
}
```

Comment: a `while` loop here would look more elegant.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh but the question was to do it without the loop