# Inserting a row after specific value - C#

Tags: c#, sql, text, reader

I have a query which give more then 500 rows and I have ordered them according to specific column say Name, and I am writing the result in a text file. 
I want to add a break record after last row of each group.
For example my query result is:

```
Name Address City State Zip   Phone   Break
AAA  BBB     CCC   SS   1234  555     
AAA  DDD     EEE   SS   1234  666
MMM  YYY     ZZZ   EE   4457  999
LLL  DDD     ooo   WW   7895  777
```

But I want to add an extra line and add "Yes" as Break value in text file as:

```
Name Address City State Zip   Phone   Break
AAA  BBB     CCC   SS   1234  555     
AAA  DDD     EEE   SS   1234  666
                                       YES
MMM  YYY     ZZZ   EE   4457  999
                                       YES
LLL  DDD     ooo   WW   7895  777
                                       YES
```

My code is:

```
string query = " select * from table order by name";
SqlDataReader reader;
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string strDelimiter = "\t";
string strDel = "\"";
string strFilePath = @"C:\" TextFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (reader = new SqlCommand(query, conn).ExecuteReader())
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(strDel);
            sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
            sb.Append(strDel);
            if (i == reader.FieldCount - 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            sb.Append(strDelimiter);
        }
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Object[] items = new Object[reader.FieldCount];

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reader.GetValues(items);
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(strDel);
                    sb.Append(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    sb.Append(strDel);
                    if (i == reader.FieldCount - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    sb.Append(strDelimiter);
                }
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: share your code until now

Comment: I updated the question with code but this just gives me all the data, I can't think a way to add the break line after each group

Answer (score 1):

```
var breakLine = new List<YourType> { new YourType { Break = "Yes"}};

var result = collection.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
                       .SelectMany(grouping => grouping.Union(breakLine))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: yep, then foreach inside each group and run your existing code above.

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui - I'd say separate logic of getting the data (the database part) and manipulating it to the file. So after you bring the data do these operations on it and put to file

Comment: You can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt) to see how to convert the output of your reader to a class and then look into linq to see how to do what I wrote above. Eventually output it to a file. Now, this is far from a must and you can also do it by other means but this was just the first thing that popped to by mind when I read the question, and before there was a code example