# Converting MySqlDataReader records to ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

I am trying to convert records from `MySqlDataReader` to `ObservableCollection<T>` but I always end up with exception - **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'**

From **[Jon Skeet's answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464929/2065039)** and referring `SLaks` comment in the same answer, I ended up writing below code but still I don't find how am getting that exception.

```
ObservableCollection<ColumnItems> DataList;
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(_query))
{
       await Global.currentConnection.OpenAsync();
       cmd.Connection = Global.currentConnection;
       MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       var dataDetails = reader.Cast<IDataReader>().Select(x => new ColumnItems
       {
             col1 = x["col1"] is DBNull ? null : x["col1"].ToString(),
             col2 = x["col2"] is DBNull ? null : x["col2"].ToString(),
             col3 = x["col3"] is DBNull ? null : x["col3"].ToString(),
             col4 = x["col4"] is DBNull ? null : x["col4"].ToString()
       });
       DataList = new ObservableCollection<ColumnItems>(dataDetails);
       //Exception while assigning data
       await Global.currentConnection.CloseAsync();
}
```

I also tried replacing `var dataDetails` with `ObservableCollection<ColumnItems> dataDetails` but again failed with no luck. I ended up finding very few resources for above exception and couldn't gather much knowledge to solve this exception. How can I fill data into my `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: reader.Cast<IDataReader>() is throwing that exception

Comment: Nope @Steve.. No exception there but `DataList = new ObservableCollection<ColumnItems>(dataDetails);` is throwing exception..

Comment: its because linq has delayed execution. it is not executed until its used. You can try reader.Cast<IDataReader>().ToList() and it should throw the same exception that you are seeing

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Steve is right: IDataReader just is not IEnumerable. You can fill empty DataTable instead (if your table is not very big).
­`DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load(reader); var dataDetails=dt.AsEnumerable().Select(...`

Comment: @Steve.. You are absolutely correct. It was throwing exception when I used `ToList()` too..

Comment: @vitalygolub.. Seems promising. Let me try this and let you know.. :)

Comment: @vitalygolub.. Perfect.. That worked as expected. Could you please add it as answer and I shall accept it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for karma :-)
IDataReader is not IEnumerable and has no method to produce IEnumerable
Fortunately, DataTable is collection of rows and can be converted to enumerable
If your table is not very big

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Load(reader); 
var dataDetails=dt.AsEnumerable().Select(...
```

Comment: Oh.. So what's the approach if the table is very big?? Around 5200 records.. :o

Comment: @GuruprasadRao use the reader to read row by row. TBH 5200 is not big

Comment: Sorry for slowness: 5200 is definitely small. It is opinion based, dependent of memory you can use to store the table. If it can be for example 52000 you can still process DataReader one by one and preserve List<ColumnItems> , but if can become 52000000, may be it is time to implement Ienumerator from reader (lack reset() method, need to requery) or inherit DBcontext instead (actualy never used MySql.Data.Entity, am not sure)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering a very old post but I happen to have this same issue/scenario with my code. I agree with the comments above that if the expected result set is small, just load the results to a DataTable and query against that instead. But if somehow you need to use LINQ directly to a Reader (aka an explicit mapper), what you need to do is to make the Reader implement IEnumerable to make it compatible with LINQ.

I used Jon Skeet's extension that I got from his answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464929/906815):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IDataReader reader,
                                       Func<IDataReader, T> projection)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return projection(reader);
    }
}
```