# Different behaviors in similar SQL Server connection string using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, connection-string

I have encountered a situation which looks weird to me. Though I have figured out another simpler way for my code to work but I'm curious to know as why this is happening. Here is the code that works absolutely perfect :

```
public DataHelper()
{
    this.dataSource = "MyMachine";
    this.initCatalog = "myDB";
    this.uid = "sa";
    this.pass = "thep@ssw0rd";
    this.conStr = "Data Source=" + dataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + initCatalog + ";User ID=" + uid + ";Password=" + pass;
    this.conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
}
```

Needless to say that this is a default constructor and the `conn` is the instance of `SqlConnection`.

But when I'm using another constructor definition:

```
public DataHelper(string constr)
{
    this.conStr = constr;
    this.conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
}
```

I find that the connection can't be opened, and the application crashes this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
>   Class=14
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060
>   HResult=-2146232060
>   LineNumber=65536
>   Message=Login failed for user 'sa'.
>   Number=18456
>   Procedure=""
>   Server=MyMachine
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   State=1
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>              at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>              at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>              at SampleWork.DataHelper.doSelect(String sql) in C:\Users\RGP\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SampleWork\SampleWork\DataHelper.cs:line 66
>              at SampleWork.DatabaseSetup.btnDataLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\RGP\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SampleWork\SampleWork\DatabaseSetup.cs:line 55
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at SampleWork.Program.Main() in C:\Users\RGP\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SampleWork\SampleWork\Program.cs:line 18
>              at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>              at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>              at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

As the exception states, below are few lines of code responsible to make the call for database connection:

**DatabaseSetup.cs**

```
private void btnDataLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbName = txtDbName.Text.Trim();
    string uid = txtUid.Text.Trim();
    string pass = txtPass.Text.Trim();
    string machine = System.Environment.MachineName;

    if (dbName.Length != 0 && uid.Length != 0 && pass.Length != 0)
    {
        string constr = "Data Source=" + machine + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName + ";Persist Security Info=True; User ID=" + uid + ";Password=" + pass;
        MessageBox.Show(constr);
        //DataHelper helper = new DataHelper();//This works
        DataHelper helper = new DataHelper(constr);//Doesn't work

        helper.doSelect("select * from abc");
    }
```

**DataHelper.cs:**

the `doSelect(string sql)` which behaves differently and throws exception depending on constructor definition:

```
public SqlDataReader doSelect(string sql)
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return reader;
}
```

Though I have also checked through breakpoints and there's nothing wrong with connection string during the execution of `doSelect()`.

Can anyone help me to understand this scenario?

Comment: The SQL Server error log will contain a message with the specific reason for the login failed error. I'm curious what that is if the connection string is identical.

Comment: @DanGuzman SQL Server is just giving error code 18456. Surprisingly this gives state 1. And if it is state 1 for error 18456 then this should be the same case for the first constructor definition in DataHelper.cs

Comment: Are you saying there is no additional text in the SQL Server error log about the cause of the error? More details should be logged, although not returned to the client.

Comment: A couple of tips: `SqlConnection` is `IDisposable`, so your `DataHelper` class should also be `IDisposable`, and when you use it, you should put it in a `using` block. `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are also disposable; but that's going to be hard to handle with this inverted design you've come up with - I wouldn't dispose Cmd before DR. Consider taking a look at [Jon Skeet's suggestion for using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464929/5198140) as guidance toward a way of encapsulating DataReader processing - this will avoid the inversion, and keep the disposal easy with a `using` block.

Comment: Thanks @Richardissimo ..for suggesting useful resource on this topic.