# How to use Generic with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, ado.net, sqlclient

I'm trying to come up with a way just to load a table from SQL Server into a class, without having to tell it anything. Basically, just create the class and have it know what to load, based on that. Here's what I have so far.

My question is, is there some way to keep from having to hard code the types, to call reader.readString, reader. readInt32, etc.. based on the FieldType?

```
 private Int32? readInt32(SqlDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        Int32? result = null;


        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName)))
        {
            result = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal(columnName));
        };

        return result;
    }

  public List<T> readTable(string table, string wherecls, string connStr)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "select * from " + table;
                if (wherecls.Length > 0) command.CommandText += " where " + wherecls;
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Object i = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

                        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldInfoList = typeof(T).GetFields();
                        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo f in fieldInfoList)
                        {
                            if (f.FieldType == typeof(string)) f.SetValue(i, readString(reader, f.Name));
                            if (f.FieldType == typeof(Int32)) f.SetValue(i, readInt32(reader, f.Name));
                            if (f.FieldType == typeof(Int16)) f.SetValue(i, readInt16(reader, f.Name));
                            if (f.FieldType == typeof(byte)) f.SetValue(i, readByte(reader, f.Name));
                            if (f.FieldType == typeof(short)) f.SetValue(i, readShort(reader, f.Name));
                        }
                        result.Add((T)i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thank you,
Dan Chase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

Comment: If you're interested in reflection techniques, you might also give the source for Fastmember a look:  https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member

Comment: @DanielB the way this question differs, I really just want to know how to get rid of all of the different if/then/SetValue's in the middle. I made almost the entire method generic, except for this and it's killing me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe is a lot of work... and is exactly what tools like "dapper" *already do*. So my suggestion here: *use dapper*:

```
// Dapper adds a Query<T>(this DbConnection, ...) extension method
var data = connection.Query<T>(sql, args).AsList();
```

I *would*, however, say that `string wherecls` sends shivers down my spine - that sounds like a SQL injection nightmare. But... that's up to you.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but if I can make readInt32 generic to readValue, then I've replaced even dapper with 2 functions..? I really just want one function.

Comment: @DanChase let the advice you've just been given really soak in.

Comment: @DanChase I cant twist your arm... just: there's no magic wand here that makes it not be a lot of work :)

Comment: I'll check out Dapper for sure, was just trying this out, also learned a lot about reflection and generics trying to do it.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for Dapper:  https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper  Some really powerful techniques used there that you can pick up on.

Comment: Thanks all! I'm actually going to mark it answered, even though my exact question wasn't really answered. Appreciate the advice, because my question only addresses one usecase of what Dapper would provide, and pointed me in the direction of the source code/etc to review the methodology.

Comment: Wow.. just.. wow. Installed Dapper eliminated 90% of my code within 5 minutes and it worked immediately without issue.!!!

Comment: @DanChase awesome! any problems / suggestions / feedback - let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Make sure the type has a public default constructor--one that takes no arguments--and that the column names in the SQL string exactly match the name of the type's public properties.

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Reflection;

    public static class MyExtensions {

        public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(this SqlConnection cn, string sql) {
            Type TypeT = typeof(T);
            ConstructorInfo ctor = TypeT.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            if (ctor == null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {TypeT.Name} does not have a default constructor.");
            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        T newInst = (T)ctor.Invoke(null);
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                            string propName = reader.GetName(i);
                            PropertyInfo propInfo = TypeT.GetProperty(propName);
                            if (propInfo != null) {
                                object value = reader.GetValue(i);
                                if (value == DBNull.Value) {
                                    propInfo.SetValue(newInst, null);
                                } else {
                                    propInfo.SetValue(newInst, value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        yield return newInst;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution is a bit better. I populate type T using extension with handling null values and populating properties in order I like.

Example:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> Search_data<T>()
    {
        var data = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connn_string))
            {
                con.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MySchema.SomeTable", con)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
              
                cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                
                using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (await rdr.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                        item.SetValue("NAME", rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? null : rdr.GetString(0));
                        item.SetValue("SURNAME", rdr.IsDBNull(1) ? null : rdr.GetString(1));
                        item.SetValue("ADDRESS", rdr.IsDBNull(2) ? null : rdr.GetString(2));
                      
                        data.Add(item);

                    };
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
             
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Extension:

```
public static void SetValue<T>(this T _source, string _property_name, object _value)
    {
        _source.GetType().GetProperty(_property_name).SetValue(_source, _value);
    }
```