# IDataReader does not have definition for Select

Tags: c#

I recently upgraded my VS2015 project to VS2017. I upgraded the .NET framework to 4.7.2 but now I get the following problem

```
    using (IDataReader rd = ExecuteCmdAndGetReader(myssqlstring))
    {
        MyList = rd.Select<myObject>(myObject.Load).ToList();
    }

    internal SqlDataReader ExecuteCmdAndGetReader(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }
```

The error is

> 'IDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I do have System.Linq in uses and System.Core in References. Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you have a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.dll?

Comment: Is ExecuteCmdAndGetReader a function you have written?

Comment: You can try creating extension method for `Select` with `IDataReader` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464929). Of course current LINQ `Select` doesn't have native support for `IDataReader`.

Comment: `IDataReader` doesn't have a `Select` function.  Is this an extension function you have created for your project and you don't have the correct usings in place to pull it in? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Your question seems to imply that in previous version of Net this code worked. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. In previous (VS2015) it was working fine

Comment: Then you are missing something in your project because Select is not a method for IDbDataReader even in previous versions of NET. Look at the comment from @Neil

Comment: @user2837961 No, probably you had your own extension method that you just forgot to reference in the new code.

Comment: Thanks all. I shall implement my extension class as below.

Comment: Hang on, @user2837961 you said it was previously working.  You need to find out why it no longer works, rather than just 'fixing it'.  Your previous implementation may have some edge-case code in it to make your project work.  You need to do some more due-diligence before randomly taking code off the internet !

Comment: Yes @Neil. I would do that instead of blindly copying code. I will have to revert lot of projects back to VS2015 and work out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDataReader doesn't implement the `IEnumerable` interface, hence no `Select` etc. LINQ methods. I suggest you could implement your own `Select` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IDataReader reader,
                                       Func<IDataReader, TResult> selector)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return selector(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why an upgrade of .NET Framework would cause the code to break.

Comment: @Stijn agree, it doesn't

Comment: Make sure Connection object is explicitly Open, Unlike DataAdapter, DataReader doesn't do it