# How to fill Dataset with multiple tables?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset, datareader

I'm trying to fill DataSet which contains 2 tables with one to many relationship.
I'm using DataReader to achieve this :

```
    public DataSet SelectOne(int id)
    {
        DataSet result = new DataSet();
        using (DbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select * from table1";

            var param = ParametersBuilder.CreateByKey(command, "ID", id, null);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            Connection.Open();
            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                result.MainTable.Load(reader);
            }
            Connection.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I've got only one table filled up. How do I achieve my goal - fill both tables?

I would like to use DataReader instead DataAdapter, if it possible.

Comment: Why would you expect that two tables are filled? Your command only contains a single `select` statement that returns a single table.

Comment: Why not use a `SqlDataAdapter` and its `Fill(...)` method instead of the `DbCommand`?

Comment: @Nikola Anusev - I know it, so I'm just asking any kind of suggestion

Comment: @jonnyGold - preformanse. DataReader is fast, DataAdapter is slower. This is critical in my case

Comment: @AndriyZakharko: The DataAdapter also uses a DataReader under the hood. http://stackoverflow.com/a/334667/284240 The only advantage of a reader is that you can stream the records one in a time instead of loading all into memory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are issuing a single command with several select statements, you might use NextResult method to move to next resultset within the datareader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx

I show how it could look bellow:

```
public DataSet SelectOne(int id)
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();
    using (DbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
select * from table1
select * from table2
        ";

        var param = ParametersBuilder.CreateByKey(command, "ID", id, null);
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        Connection.Open();
        using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            result.MainTable.Load(reader);
            reader.NextResult();
            result.SecondTable.Load(reader);
            // ...
        }
        Connection.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can just do `result.Load(reader)`. The `Load` method will handle multiple result-sets.

Comment: @AMissico, true but which table to fill with which resultset can't be explicitly stated with DataSet.Load, it will break if you define tables in another order.

Also you have to state other parameters.

Comment: you made me smile today.

Answer (score 37):

Filling a DataSet with multiple tables can be done by sending multiple requests to the database, or in a faster way: Multiple SELECT statements can be sent to the database server in a single request. The problem here is that the tables generated from the queries have automatic names Table and Table1. However, the generated table names can be mapped to names that should be used in the DataSet.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT * FROM Customers; SELECT * FROM Orders", connection);
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Customer");
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Order");

adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but according my task - I need to use DataReader instead DataAdapter : that was described in my question

Comment: adding with TableMappings.Add is not neccassarry

Comment: @Iman - it might not be necessary if you're sending SQL to the server as per the example, but it is if you're calling a stored-procedure and returning multiple SELECTs. This answer was very useful to me

Answer (score 8):

It is an old topic, but for some people it might be useful:

```
        DataSet someDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();

        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM whateverTable", connection);
            SqlCommand comm2g = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM whateverTable WHERE condition = @0", connection);
            commProcessing.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", "value");
            someDataSet.Tables.Add("Table1");
            someDataSet.Tables.Add("Table2");

            adapt.SelectCommand = comm1;
            adapt.Fill(someDataSet.Tables["Table1"]);
            adapt.SelectCommand = comm2;
            adapt.Fill(someDataSet.Tables["Table2"]);
        }
```

Comment: how can handle this situation, if sql(store proc) returning multiple tables?

Comment: Instead of doing `adapt.Fill(someDataSet.Tables["Table1"])` you would do `adapt.Fill(someDataSet)`. Because ofcourse your stored procedure retruns the tables, but only if it really returns TABLES and not a set of COLUMNS from multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for response, will try this thing :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Here is very good answer of your question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/867whzw2.aspx)

see the example mentioned on above MSDN page :-

Answer (score 3):

Method `Load` of `DataTable` executes `NextResult` on the `DataReader`, so you shouldn't call `NextResult` explicitly when using `Load`, otherwise odd tables in the sequence would be omitted.

Here is a generic solution to load multiple tables using a `DataReader`.

```
public static DataSet DataSetFromReader(IDataReader reader)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    while (!reader.IsClosed)
    {
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Load(reader);
        ds.Tables.Add(t);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me, very useful when I'm unsure how many separate tables are being returned in a stored proc (as I just found out when hitting a legacy db with encrypted stored procs)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=shop");
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblemployees", con);
    //SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tblproducts", con);
    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //ds.Tables.Add("emp");
    //ds.Tables.Add("products");
    //da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    //da.Fill(ds.Tables["emp"]);
    //da.SelectCommand = cmd1;

    //da.Fill(ds.Tables["products"]);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblemployees", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "em");
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblproducts", con);
    da.Fill(ds, "prod");

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["em"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["prod"];
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
         string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection ;
        SqlCommand command ;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string firstSql = null;
        string secondSql = null;

        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
        firstSql = "Your First SQL Statement Here";
        secondSql = "Your Second SQL Statement Here";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand(firstSql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "First Table");

            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = secondSql;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Second Table");

            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

            //retrieve first table data 
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " -- " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
            }
            //retrieve second table data 
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " -- " + ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Core.con))
            {
                string query = "select * from table1;  select* from table2";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dsReturn.Load(reader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, new string[] { "tableOne", "tableTwo" });
                return dsReturn;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (!reader.IsClosed)
         {
              ds.Tables.Add().Load(reader);
         }
}
return ds;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.