# DbDataReader, NextResult() and filling more than one table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset, datareader

This question is continuation of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345761/how-to-fill-dataset-with-multiple-tables) one. Without going into too much details, I'm filling dataset with 2 related 1-to-many tables.
So, my question now is - why this code works good

```
public DataAgencyR_DataSet SelectOne(int id)
{
    DataAgencyR_DataSet result = new DataAgencyR_DataSet();
    using (DbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {               
            command.CommandText = SqlStrings.SelectDataAgencyR_SelectOne();

            var param = ParametersBuilder.CreateByKey(command, "ID_DeclAgenc", id, "ID_DeclAgenc");
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            Connection.Open();
            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}-{1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("-------------");
                reader.NextResult();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}-{1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (DbException e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.Message, e);
            throw new DataAccessException("Error occurs while SelectOne method porcessed", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)                     Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static string SelectDataAgencyR_SelectOne()
{
    return "SELECT a.* FROM t0_DataAgency_R a WHERE a.SetToPartners = 1 AND a.ID_DeclAgenc = @ID_DeclAgenc;" +
                   "SELECT c.* FROM t01_ChoiceParam_R c JOIN t0_DataAgency_R a on a.ID_DeclAgenc = c.ID_DeclAgenc WHERE SetToPartners = 1 AND a.ID_DeclAgenc = @ID_DeclAgenc";
}
```

and this is not

```
public DataAgencyR_DataSet SelectOne(int id)
{
    DataAgencyR_DataSet result = new DataAgencyR_DataSet();

    using (DbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {               
            command.CommandText = SqlStrings.SelectDataAgencyR_SelectOne();             
            var param = ParametersBuilder.CreateByKey(command, "ID_DeclAgenc", id, "ID_DeclAgenc");
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            Connection.Open();
            using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                result.t0_DataAgency_R.Load(reader);
                reader.NextResult();
                result.t01_ChoiceParam_R.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (DbException e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.Message, e);
            throw new DataAccessException("Error occurs while SelectOne method porcessed", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public static string SelectDataAgencyR_SelectOne()
{
    return "SELECT a.* FROM t0_DataAgency_R a WHERE a.SetToPartners = 1 AND a.ID_DeclAgenc = @ID_DeclAgenc;" +
                   "SELECT c.* FROM t01_ChoiceParam_R c JOIN t0_DataAgency_R a on a.ID_DeclAgenc = c.ID_DeclAgenc WHERE SetToPartners = 1 AND a.ID_DeclAgenc = @ID_DeclAgenc";
}
```

After second example, I have filled only result.t0_DataAgency_R table - but not result.t01_ChoiceParam_R. Why can it be so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DataTable.Load` automatically advances the reader to the next result. So you should remove your explicit call to `NextResult`.

Meaning:

```
using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    result.t0_DataAgency_R.Load(reader);
    result.t01_ChoiceParam_R.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: what if there is a variable number of result sets? How can you check when to stop checking for nextresult?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a DataSet to the mix... we used to use SqlDataAdapter and returned a DataSet but didn't take advantage of any of the offline features, etc., so a SqlDataReader is a better fit. Here's code to fill a DataSet. Found this was about 10% faster overall.

```
                Dim s As DataSet = New DataSet()

                Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim tables As New List(Of DataTable)
                    Do
                        Dim table As New DataTable()
                        table.Load(reader)
                        tables.Add(table)
                        s.Tables.Add(table)
                    Loop While Not reader.IsClosed

                    s.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, tables.ToArray())
                End Using
```