# filling dataset using data adapter

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code is as follows.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", accountNumberLong);
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM T_POSTAGE_DISCOUNT");
sqlQuery = sql.ToString();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dsDiscounts, "Discounts");
}
```

upto here its working fine. I want to add another table to this dataset. Then I did like this.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR",discountLevelNBR);
sql.AppendLine("select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR");
sqlQuery = sql.ToString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dsDiscounts,"CONTRACT");

}
```

Its adding all the tables again. I want to add onlt contract table to existing datatset.
How can I do that?(c#)

Comment: I think you are appending the query again "sql.AppendLine("select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR");", so when you are executing for the second time it executes both...

Comment: Actually its a seperate query.Table names are different in both the queries.What should i do now?

Comment: create a new string builder StringBuilder sql1 = new StringBuilder(); and then sql1.AppendLine("select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR"); sqlQuery = sql1.ToString();

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11345761/3030434)

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable("MyTable");
adapter.Fill(myTable);
ds.Tables.Add(myTable);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in brief?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from appending line you done it two time on string sql,
when you write `sql.AppendLine("...");`
the string 
`sql = "select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR"`.

Then in other line you add a command to string sql again so it become
`sql = "select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR" "select * from T_CONTRACT WHERE DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR=@DISCOUNT_LEVEL_NBR"`
So it is clear why it brings all table again.
So it is good to use two string sql1 , sql2.