# C# - Select Data from two tables in SQL to Dataset

Tags: c#, sql, database, dataset, oledb

I have two tables in my database, (Users and Cities) and I want to select all the data in this tables where the column UserID=1 in Users table.

But the Dataset does not find my tables (Users and Cities)

This is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Cities ON Cities.CityID=Users.CityID WHERE Users.UserID=1
```

And this is the Mathod:

```
public static DataSet GetData(string SqlQuery)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

Code:

```
    DataSet ds = GetData(myQuery);

    string fname = ds.Tables["Users"].Rows[0]["UserFisrtName"].ToString();
    string lname = ds.Tables["Users"].Rows[0]["UserLastName"].ToString();
    string city = ds.Tables["Cities"].Rows[0]["CityName"].ToString();

    string output = "Name: " + fname + " " + lname + " City: " + city;
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345761/how-to-fill-dataset-with-multiple-tables)

Comment: Why are you using oleDB instead of SQLClient for a SQL database?  If your connection string doesn't specify the Database name then you need to add USE XXXdb in the query.

Comment: I'm using access database

Comment: There is no need to reference the table name in your data set. The Join will return data in a single table. All the columns will be in table zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2 datatables in the data set, change the sql query to this.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.UserID=1; select * from City where CityID in (Select cityid from users where userID = 1);
```

The user table will then be on ds.Tables[0] and the city table on ds.Tables[1].

Please remember to use the using clause to ensure connections, etc are properly disposed.

```
public static DataSet GetData(string SqlQuery)
{
    using(var con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con))
    using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
var ds = GetData(myQuery);
var fname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserFisrtName"].ToString();
var lname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserLastName"].ToString();
var city = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CityName"].ToString();
var output = "Name: " + fname + " " + lname + " City: " + city;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, in the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM Users, Cities WHERE Users.CityID=Cities.CityID AND Users.UserID=1
```

Comment: So you're saying that using old-style joins adds _two_ tables to the `DataSet`?

Comment: EEP! That's horrible, I havent see that syntax in over a decade. PLEASE Use "JOIN" syntax when joining tables ...

Answer (score 0):

In a Dataset your tables will not automatically have the names of the tables from which they are selected. Use the ordinals instead:

```
DataSet ds = GetData(myQuery);
string fname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserFisrtName"].ToString();
string lname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserLastName"].ToString();
string city = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CityName"].ToString();

string output = "Name: " + fname + " " + lname + " City: " + city;
```

Comment: I corrected my response. Note that even though you are selecting from two distinct tables, the join will result in a single "table" of data. As such it is not necessary to return a data set, you could just use a data reader. As it is, all of the columns you address should be available on `Tables[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the dataset only with one table, this because the Sql statement only return a one set of data. For access the tables you use indexes, only the columns name will be mapped in the rows of the table so this values can be access by index or by name.

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Cities ON Cities.CityID=Users.CityID WHERE Users.UserID=1
```

Also avoid use `SELECT *` this because you force the database engine to search for the columns of all the tables instead to only use the you already provided, and if you will not use all or someone change te order of it in the table, can be a future problem.