# Which one will run faster?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is datareader quicker than dataset when populating a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334658/is-datareader-quicker-than-dataset-when-populating-a-datatable)

```
 public DataTable GetReviewsId(Objects myObjects)
 {
     DataTable tblBindReviews = new DataTable();
     string Query = "";
     try
     {
         Query = "select distinct ProductId from tblReview where ProductId in (select ProductId from tblProduct where R=0 and T=0)";
         /*SqlConnection mySqlConnection = this.SetDatabaseConnection();
         SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, mySqlConnection);
         mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(tblBindReviews);*/
         /*mySqlConnection.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query,mySqlConnection);
         tblBindReviews.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());*/
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         this.ClosedatabaseConnection();
     }
     return tblBindReviews;
 }
```

In the above code i have written two ways(each inside the commented part) of retrieving data, one using data adapter and the other using datareader. which one of the two will run faster?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: Have you run a test over your sample data set?  `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is your friend for these types of questions.

Comment: What makes you think there is even a difference between the two options?

Comment: i tried but they seem to give me the same result while debugging using visual studio 2010..

Comment: Use a larger data set or run your test inside a loop. If you are concerned about Debug vs Release, try on both. If you get the same or undistinguishable performance, then which one is probably up to you.

Comment: @jheddings..can you tell me how i can use the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ..can i just include it in my code

Comment: The docs have a nice example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx  Of course, instead of sleeping, you would access your database.

Answer (score 3):

DataReader is the fastest way. 
In any case faster then DataAdapter as DataAdapter uses DataReaders inside and performs additional operations (works with datasets multiple tables, .....)

[image: DbDataAdapter - FillInternalMethod]

Comment: How can you make this claim considering how simple the query is?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute `select operations` i suggets you to use `SqlDataReader`

Only has one record in memory at a time rather than an entire result set

Is about as fast as it you can get for that one iteration

Allows you start processing results sooner

Nota :

With SqlDataAdapter you have Much higher memory use, you wait until all the data is loaded before using any of it