# Using DataTable.Load() method is not working in case two resultsets returned by DataReader

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, sqldatareader

With the motive of enhancing the performance I am trying to eliminate Dataset use & implement DataReader. Here my Oracle Procedure returning two refcursors & when I am loading the first recordset in to the first DataTable, the next one never gets loaded.

Sample code looks something like this :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (OracleConnection db = new OracleConnection(conString))
        {
            try
            {
                using (OracleCommand mycom = new OracleCommand())
                {
                    mycom.CommandText = "myPkg.pr_mySP";
                    mycom.Connection = db;
                    mycom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    mycom.Parameters.Add("ref_list1", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    mycom.Parameters.Add("ref_list2", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    //mycom.FetchSize = mycom.FetchSize * 64;

                    db.Open();
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = mycom.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        DataTable custMapList = new DataTable("dtcustMapList");
                        custMapList.Load(reader);

                        reader.NextResult(); // POST THIS THE SECOND DATATABLE DOESNOT GETTING POPULATED 
                        DataTable custMapSubList = new DataTable("dtcustMapSubList");
                        custMapSubList.Load(reader);

                        ds.Tables.Add(custMapList);
                        ds.Tables.Add(custMapSubList);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnString += "Error, " + ex.Message;
            }
```

I know there are alternative methods like looping using while(reader.Read()) ... & then using reader.NextResult() will work, but in that case I have to change many other codes which I think can be avoided if the above works fine.

Appreciate an early response.

Comment: I am not certain, but IIRC Datareader's use a high-speed sequential streaming pipeline model.  That would imply that you have to completely consume one dataset before you can move on to the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,a907a83034e99786) for the `DataTable.Load` method it is clear that the method calls `NextResult()` before exiting, so you don't need to do it.

```
 ....
 if(!reader.IsClosed && !reader.NextResult())
      reader.Close();
 ....
```

And by the way, there is no need to go to the source. Also MSDN says:

> The Load method consumes the first result set from the loaded
>   IDataReader, and after successful completion, sets the reader's
>   position to the next result set, if any.

So you just need to remove this line

```
// reader.NextResult(); // POST THIS THE SECOND DATATABLE DOESNOT GETTING POPULATED
```

Comment: I hope DataTable.Load() approach is as good as looping row by row & retrieving values by keeping in a while loop.

Comment: If you are looking for the max performance then probably you could use your own loop over the DataReader. A lot depends on where and what are you doing with the data retrieved. There are lot of questions on performances of DataAdapter.Fill vs DataTable.Load, here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334658/is-datareader-quicker-than-dataset-when-populating-a-datatable